# Python - Im trying to make a function that would add "*" in between each letter

Tags: python, function

I have this:

```py
def f(message):
    l = []
    for c in message:
     l.append(c)
     l.append('*')
    return "".join(l)
```

It works but how do I make it so that it doesn't add "*" at the end. I only want it to be between the inputted word. I'm new to python and was just trying new things.

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try this. It uses list comprehension

```
input_str = 'dog'

def f(x):
    return '*'.join(x)

print(f('dog')) #ouput d*o*g
print(f(input_str)) #ouput d*o*g
```

Comment: No need to convert the string to a list, strings are iterable already.  `'*'.join(x)` works fine.

Comment: You are right @MarkRansom ... I will modify my answer your comment

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you could just slice the returned string cutting off the last astrix.

```
message="dog"
def f(message):
    l = []   
    for c in message:              
        l.append(c)              
        l.append('*')         
    return "".join(l[:-1])
print(f(message))
```

this way it returns

```
d*o*g
```